# Start without debugging script in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: web-applications, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2013

I am writing a number of test cases and am trying to start the web application without debugging. I can do this by clicking Ctrl + F5 before I start debugging the tests. (If I do not start the application before running the test, the webpage says it is 'unavailable'.

I am looking for a script to start the application so I can put it in my first test without having to worry about clicking "ctrl-f5" everytime I need to debug the tests.

Surely there is a way to do this? If all else fails, directing Selenium Webdriver to click "Ctrl + F5" might be the solution. Hopefully there is a more elegant way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to start your web application from within your debug tests, so that your tests never run without the application already running?